# Jquery - auto complete with clickable links

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I have implemented search module with jqueryUI autocomplete in which search suggestions are rendered with their category.
Now i want to make those suggestions clickable,I've already tried select function but its not working,now i stuck in it
My Jquery Code is

```
  $( function() {
   $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
_renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
    var that = this, 
        currentCategory = "";
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        if (item.category != currentCategory) {
            ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
            currentCategory = item.category;
        }
        that._renderItemData(ul, item);
     });
     }
   });
   $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
   source : function(request,response){
    var term = $("#search").val();
    $.ajax({
      type : "GET",
      url : "ajax/auto_search.php",
      dataType : "json",
      data : {term : term},
      success : function(data)
      {
        console.log(data);
        response($.map(data.list, function(item) {

                return {
                    value: item.content_title,
                    label: item.content_title,
                    category: item.category_name,
                    url : item.url
                }

        }))
      },
        select: function( event, ui ) { 
          //main problem is with item.content_title unable to get its value
        window.location.href = 'search.php?mode=content_type&query='+item.content_title;
      }

      });
     }
    });
   });
```

**php code is**

```
<?php
 include '../includes/dbconfig.php';
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
 $sql = "SELECT distinct content_title,        c.content_title,p.category_name,c.content_url from content_ref_table c  inner join category_ref_table p on p.category_id = c.category_id where c.content_title LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY c.content_title ASC LIMIT 0,10";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
 $data_array = array();
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
     $data_array['list'][] = array("content_title" => $row['content_title'], "category_name" => $row['category_name'],"url" => $row['content_url'] );
  }
 echo json_encode($data_array);
?>
```

**EDIT: how Can I store the item.content_title in a global variable?i think if i'm able to store the item.content_title in variable then it can solve my problem  **